# Spring Integration Kafka - Exception Handling by using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

Problem Statement :

1. Need to handle exceptions occur while consuming messages in kafka
2. Commit failed offset
3. Seek to the next unprocessed offset, so that next polling start from this offset.

Seems all these are handled as part of SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java in Spring-Kafka.

How to leverage this functionality in Spring-Integration-Kafka ?

Please help with this.

Versions used :
Spring-Integration-Kafka - 3.3.1
Spring for apache kafka - 2.5.x

```
@Bean(name ="kafkaConsumerFactory")
public ConsumerFactory consumerFactory0(
  HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>(); 
  properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafkaServerl"); 
  properties.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class); 
  properties.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class); 
  properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
} return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactoryo(properties);  I


@Bean("customKafkalistenerContainer")
public ConcurrentMessagelistenerContainerCtring, AddAccountReqRes> customKafkaListenerContainer() ( 
  ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("Topici");
  containerProps.setGroupld("Groupldl");
  return (ConcurrentMessagelistenerContainerCtring, CustomReqRes>) new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>( 
}  kafkaConsumerFactory, containerProps);

IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(customKafkalistenerContainer, KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.record) 
     .errorChannel(errorChannel()))
     .handle(transformationProcessor, "process")
     .channel("someChannel")
     .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring-integration-kafka` uses spring-kafka underneath, so you just need to configure the adapter's container with the error handler.

`spring-integration-kafka` was moved to spring-integration starting with 5.4 (it was an extension previously). So, the current versions of both jars is 5.4.2.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Missing to understand how exceptions could be handled for kafka using this adapter's container. 
Would you please help by providing with any url having code snippet for this.
Also we would not be able to move to latest versions of spring-integration as of now.

Comment: Edit the question to show your spring integration configuration beans, so we can tell you what you need to change. I can't guess at your current configuration. I just added that note about 5.4 for general information. 5.3.x with 3.3.1 is still supported.

Comment: Hi Gary Russell, I had updated configurations in above question. 
Would you please help with generic functionality with which we can handle seektocurrenterrorhandler.java logic in spring-integration flows while handling connector flows exceptions.

Comment: In your `customKafkaListenerContainer` `@Bean` set the error handler with desired properties on the container.